# Can't resolve 'core-js/client/shim — Upgrade Angular from v6 to v7

Tags: angular

After upgrade new version of Angular that error occurs:

```
Can't resolve 'core-js/client/shim
```

In `main.ts` I have code:

```
// Shim the environment
import 'core-js/client/shim';
```

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Answer (score 4):

Try to replace:

```
// Shim the environment
import 'core-js/client/shim';
```

by:

```
// Shim the environment
import 'core-js/features/reflect';
```

**Angular** use **Reflecting** to make **Dependency Injection works**.